# Linux Subsystem can't install and recognize packages

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using windows and didn't wanted to switch to linux. I still wanted to learn it so I downloaded ubuntu subsystem for windows. It works fine and I can also execute linux commands on it. But the problem is I can't check my pip version using "pip --version" command also I can't access nodejs . It says that node isn't recognized. But it is working fine on my cmd windows terminal. How can I make it work ? Do I really have to download all these packages again after running "sudo apt update" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to download all these packages again for Ubuntu-WSL. That is because WSL is not compatible with windows executable, just like Ubuntu is supposed to be.

Comment: @FarazKhan Glad to help